# Error when trying to load getorgchart using ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, getorgchart

I'm trying to load getorgchart using loadFromJSON, but I'm getting the following message: "Cannot read property 'children' of undefined". Here is my code:

```
    var peopleElement = document.getElementById("people");
    var orgChart = new getOrgChart(peopleElement, {
        primaryFields: ["name", "title", "phone", "mail"],
        expandToLevel: 100,
        layout: getOrgChart.MIXED_HIERARCHY_RIGHT_LINKS
    });

    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("deptosGetOrg", "Deptos")',
        success: function (data) {
            var model = JSON.stringify({ 'dataSource': data })
            orgChart.loadFromJSON(model, true);
        }

    });
```

Here is the result from ajax request:

```
{ id = "58", parentId = null, name = "DIRECCION GENERAL", title = "  ,", mail = "correo@dominio.com" }  
{ id = "59", parentId = "58", name = "DIRECCION GENERAL ASISTENTE", title = "AP AM ,Nombre", mail = "correo@dominio.com" }  
{ id = "60", parentId = "58", name = "DIRECCION DE AUDITORIA INTERNA CORPORATIVA REGIONA", title = "  ,", mail = "correo@dominio.com" } 
{ id = "61", parentId = "58", name = "DIRECCION COMERCIAL DE PAIS", title = "  ,", mail = "correo@dominio.com" }    
{ id = "62", parentId = "58", name = "DIRECCION DE COMPRAS Y LOGISTICA REGIONAL", title = "  ,", mail = "correo@dominio.com" }  
{ id = "63", parentId = "58", name = "DIRECCION DE FINANZAS REGIONAL", title = "AP AM ,Nombre", mail = "correo@dominio.com" }   
{ id = "64", parentId = "58", name = "DIRECCION JURIDICA REGIONAL", title = "  ,", mail = "correo@dominio.com" }    
{ id = "65", parentId = "58", name = "DIRECCION DE SISTEMAS REGIONAL", title = "  ,", mail = "correo@dominio.com" } 
{ id = "66", parentId = "58", name = "DIRECCION DE SERVICIO AL CLIENTE REGIONAL", title = "  ,", mail = "correo@dominio.com" }  
{ id = "67", parentId = "58", name = "DIRECCION DE INGENIERIA Y OPERACIONES REGIONAL", title = "  ,", mail = "correo@dominio.com" } 
{ id = "68", parentId = "58", name = "DIRECCION DE MERCADEO Y COMERCIAL CENTRO AMERICA", title = "  ,", mail = "correo@dominio.com" }   
{ id = "69", parentId = "58", name = "DIRECCION PROYECTOS Y TECNOLOGIA REGIONAL", title = "  ,", mail = "correo@dominio.com" }  
{ id = "70", parentId = "58", name = "DIRECCION REC.HUMANOS/REGULACION INTERCON.REGIONAL", title = "  ,", mail = "correo@dominio.com" } 
{ id = "71", parentId = "58", name = "DIRECCION COMERCIAL SVA REGIONAL", title = "  ,", mail = "correo@dominio.com" }   
{ id = "72", parentId = "58", name = "DIRECCION VENTAS MERCADO CORPORATIVO", title = "  ,", mail = "correo@dominio.com" }   
{ id = "76", parentId = "59", name = "GERENCIA DE TIENDAS PROPIAS", title = "AP AM ,Nombre", mail = "correo@dominio.com" }  
{ id = "77", parentId = "59", name = "GERENCIA FINANCIERA", title = "AP AM ,Nombre", mail = "correo@dominio.com" }  
{ id = "79", parentId = "60", name = "GERENCIA DE ASEGURAMIENTO DE INGRESOS", title = "  ,", mail = "correo@dominio.com" }  
{ id = "80", parentId = "60", name = "GERENCIA DE AUDITORIA INTERNA", title = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", mail = "xxxx@dominio.com" }   
{ id = "81", parentId = "60", name = "GERENCIA DE ANALISIS Y RIESGO REGIONAL", title = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", mail = "xxxx@dominio.com" }   
{ id = "82", parentId = "61", name = "GERENCIA DE ESTRATEGIA COMERCIAL", title = "xxxxxxxxxxxx", mail = "xxxx@dominio.com" }    
{ id = "83", parentId = "61", name = "GERENCIA MERCADEO/DESARROLLO COMERCIAL", title = "xxxxxxxxxxxx", mail = "xxxx@dominio.com" }  
{ id = "84", parentId = "61", name = "GERENCIA DE VENTAS INMOBILIARIAS", title = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", mail = "xxxx@dominio.com" }  
{ id = "85", parentId = "61", name = "GERENCIA DE OPERACIONES COMERCIALES PARA DISTRIBUI", title = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", mail = "xxxxxxx@dominio.com" }    
{ id = "89", parentId = "62", name = "GERENCIA DE COMPRAS", title = "  ,", mail = "correo@dominio.com" }    
{ id = "90", parentId = "62", name = "GERENCIA DE LOGISTICA REGIONAL", title = "xxxxxx", mail = "xxxxxxx@dominio.com" }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just `orgChart.loadFromJSON(data, true);` (not `model`)

Comment: Thanks, Stephen. I've got the exact same error. After your comment I did a test copying a few records only (around 20) using the "dataSource" parameter and everything went fine, so my format is ok. However, I tried to copy yhe 600 records and got the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined" message. I tried to load only 20 using ajax and got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the second parameter

orgChart.loadFromJSON(model);

Here is working example with your data: http://www.getorgchart.com/Experimental/test24.html

Comment: Thanks! Now I can see the orgchart displayed correctly. However, when I try to load all departments from my organization (almost 600) it doesn't show anything. I did a test with up to 200 and it worked fine. Is there a limitation on the number of departments the component can display?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem might be the JSON response. Look at the end of every block: it should have a comma (,) separating each one. Try this response:

```
{ id = "58", parentId = null, name = "DIRECCION GENERAL", title = "  ,", mail = "correo@dominio.com" },
{ id = "59", parentId = "58", name = "DIRECCION GENERAL ASISTENTE", title = "AP AM ,Nombre", mail = "correo@dominio.com" }
```